# What's the difference? ASSEMBLER

Tags: assembly

What's the difference between

```
mov bl, byte [ecx]
```

to

```
mov byte bl, [ecx]
```

?

Comment: byte is placed in a different position

Comment: There shouldn't be a difference in terms of compiled output, although one or the other may be required by a specific assembler

Comment: What's does it mean? will it assign the [ecx] in bl in difference way?

Comment: One is valid and the other isn't?

Comment: I don't know, I saw a code with the first one, and until now I used the second. Maybe it's different, that's why I'm asking

Answer (score 1):

This is assembler-specific, but `byte` or - I believe more formally - `byte ptr` is a type specifier that tells the assembler what size the operands are.

Here, you are moving to a byte-sized register, so the size specifier is redundant, but it is required for, say,

```
cmp byte ptr [ebx], 1
```

because the assembler would not otherwise know what size the operands are.

Comment: `byte ptr` is more or less a MASMism. Most assemblers using an Intel syntax outside of MASM and clones(TASM/JWASM etc) don't use the `ptr`